# Unable to publish App using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

[image: Publish option is not highlighted]

Publish option is greyed out and is not selectable?

The App form can be accessed on clicking the 'Apps' button located between the 'Reset' button and the Settings icon on the Code editor.[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  How did you reach the form that you have in your picture?

Answer (score 1):

You must associate your app with a Google Cloud Project as per the second section in the form.